# html empty select resizes when an element is added

Tags: html

I have an empty select component with a fixed width that has options added to it by Javascript. It uses a scrollbar by default. When the page loads, this element isn't quite the right height. When an option is added, the select element resizes to the correct height and stays that way until the page is reloaded or the list of options cleared. Is there a way I can make the selector load at the correct height *without* initializing it with an option?

```js
function addOpt() {
  let selector = document.getElementById("selector");
  let opt = document.createElement("option");
  opt.innerHTML = "New option";
  selector.appendChild(opt);
}
```

```html
<select size="8" style="width: 250px;" id="selector">
</select>
<br /><br />
<button type="button" onclick="addOpt()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: For me, the `select` height stays the same on Safari, and nudges a little bit on adding the first element, then stays the same on Chrome.

Comment: it moves pretty dramatically in firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getSelectHeight(rowsCount) {
            var rowsHtml = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
                rowsHtml += '<option>.</option>';

            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = '<select size="' + rowsCount + '" style="width: 250px;visibility:hidden">' + rowsHtml + '</select>';
            document.body.after(div);

            var height = div.offsetHeight;
            div.remove();
            return height;
        }

        function setSelectorHeight() {
            var select = document.getElementById('selector');
            var rowsCount = select.getAttribute('size');
            select.style.height = getSelectHeight(rowsCount) + 'px';
        }

        function addOpt() {

            let selector = document.getElementById("selector");
            let opt = document.createElement("option");
            opt.innerHTML = "New option";
            selector.appendChild(opt);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="setSelectorHeight()">

    <select size="8" style="width: 250px" id="selector"></select>

    <button type="button" onclick="addOpt()">Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

`getSelectHeight` give us the real height of the selector with the specified `rowsCount`. Here we add a non visible selector with `rowsCount` items, get the real height of it and remove the selector.

On body `onload` we run `setSelectorHeight`: find our selector, check the number of rows (`size` attribute) and set the height of the selector. I use the style because setting `offsetHeight` doesn't work.

Comment: this is sort of ingenious, thank you